# Questionmark in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, migration

I have this Oracle SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO document_status (result_row_id, timestamp, username,
    status_type, status, comment_text, document, document_file, assigned_to)
VALUES (?, SYSTIMESTAMP, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I want to convert this statement to a SQL Server statement but I do not know an equivalent parameter for the question marks in `VALUES (?, SYSTIMESTAMP, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`
What can I do?

Comment: Are you seeing this code being run _directly_ against Oracle, or does this appear in some application programming language, like Java or C#?

Comment: yes it is in Java, I thought that this would be SQL statements and was wondering why they didnt work as SQL queries in SQL Server Management Studio but now it is fixed, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, what you are looking at is almost certainly a prepared statement, possibly being run from Java or C#.  The `?` you see are placeholders for actual values, which will be bound to the statement later on.  So, the only thing you might have to change here is the literal `SYSTIMESTAMP`.  SQL Server uses `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` for this:

```
INSERT INTO document_status (result_row_id, timestamp, username, status_type, status,
    comment_text, document, document_file, assigned_to)
VALUES
    (?, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Variable in sql-server :

```
DECLARE   @result_row_id    INT
        , @username         VARCHAR(100)
        , @status_type      VARCHAR(100)
        , @status           VARCHAR(100)
        , @comment_text     VARCHAR(100)
        , @document         VARCHAR(100)
        , @document_file    VARCHAR(100)
        , @assigned_to      VARCHAR(100)


INSERT INTO document_status 
(
      result_row_id
    , timestamp
    , username
    , status_type
    , status
    , comment_text
    , document
    , document_file
    , assigned_to
)
VALUES 
(
      @result_row_id
    , GETDATE()
    , @username
    , @status_type
    , @status
    , @comment_text
    , @document
    , @document_file
    , @assigned_to
)
```